# Typescript interface generator of API PLATFORM is not working

Tags: typescript, api-platform.com

I have a problem with one of the API Platform libraries ([API Platform Create Client](https://github.com/api-platform/create-client)).
I'm trying to generate typescript interfaces to document the App clients that will use my Api.
In the official [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/create-client/typescript/) they asked me to type this command:

```bash
npm init @api-platform/client --generator typescript https://demo.api-platform.com src/
```

but when I type it nothing happens. I have this result in the console

```bash
Usage: index entrypoint outputDirectory

Generate apps built with Next, Nuxt, Quasar, React, React Native, Vue or Vuetify for any API documented using Hydra or OpenAPI

Options:
  -V, --version                                 output the version number
  -r, --resource [resourceName]                 Generate CRUD for the given resource
  -p, --hydra-prefix [hydraPrefix]              The hydra prefix used by the API (default: "hydra:")
  --username [username]                         Username for basic auth (Hydra only)
  --password [password]                         Password for basic auth (Hydra only)
  --bearer [bearer]                             Token for bearer auth (Hydra only)
  -g, --generator [generator]                   The generator to use, one of "next", "nuxt", "quasar", "react", "react-native", "typescript", "vue", "vuetify" or a path to a custom generator of your choice (default:
                                                "next")
  -t, --template-directory [templateDirectory]  The templates directory base to use. Final directory will be ${templateDirectory}/${generator} (default:
                                                "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\621bcd6ea5cd5b17\\node_modules\\@api-platform\\create-client\\lib/../templates/")
  -f, --format [hydra|openapi3|openapi2]        "hydra", "openapi3" or "openapi2" (default: "hydra")
  -s, --server-path [serverPath]                Path to express server file to allow route dynamic addition (Next.js generator only)
  -h, --help                                    display help for command
```

Can you please help me